# Java Abstract Classes with two Generics

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I have a question regarding Java abstract classes with generic data types. In the last exam we needed to implement a abstract class with two generic data types like this:

```
public abstract class Machine<P, R> {

    public List<R> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public abstract P findRessources();
}
```

in the first subclass we had to implement conveyor class like this:

```
public class Conveyor extends Machine<P, R>{

    @Override
    public P findRessources() {
        return null;
    }
```

and in the second subclass we had to implement a Propeller class, which turns two blades into a propeller:

```
public class Propeller extends Machine<Blade, Propeller>{
    @Override
    public Blade findRessources() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get an error in the subclasses, that P, R, Blade and Propeller can't be resolved.  I searched already on the web, how to implement an abstract class with two generic data types, but there was no satisfying solution for my case.

Comment: Please provide the exact compiler error, not your summary of the error. In any case your code provides no `Blade` class, which accounts for one problem, second `Conveyor` is not correctly generified (you're specifying two classes `P` and `R`, which don't exist, instead of two type parameters). You need to use `public class Conveyor<P, R> extends Machine<P, R>`, this accounts for two problems, and then because `Propeller` can't be compiled, you have the fourth problem.

Comment: Also: what do you think `class Conveyor extends Machine<P, R>` means? Should this be a generic conveyor? Then you need `class Conveyor<P, R> extends Machine<P, R>`.

Comment: I think you should clarify what Conveyor and Propeller need to do. You also need to complete a crash course on generics to understand what/how are the parameterized types used.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `Conveyor` to be a generic class too, it should be declared with generic type parameters:

```
public class Conveyor<P, R> extends Machine<P, R>
```

If you want `Propeller` to extend `Machine<Blade, Propeller>`, where `Blade` and `Propeller` are actual class names (i.e. they are not generic type parameters), you must define these classes.

Comment: Another option is to make the Conveyor class extend Machine, with no generic types.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea that would mean using `Machine` as a raw type, which is not a good idea. And it will force you to change the return type of the `findRessources()` implementation to `Object`.

Comment: So the right way for the Propeller class would be:
`public class Propeller<Blade, Propeller> extends Machine<P,R>`
right?

Comment: The problem in the first subclass is now done. But in the second it always says `public class Propeller<Blade, Propeller> extends Machine<P,R>` that P and R can not be resolved..

Comment: @MichiSch you need to tell the compiler who P and R are. You probably want `class Propeller extends Machine<Blade, Propeller>`

Comment: @Eran I am well aware of that, it is still an option, even though it's not good to go with raw types.

Comment: @MichiSch The declaration `class Propeller extends Machine<Blade, Propeller>` makes no sense to me. The second type parameter is used by the superclass to define a list of them. But why should a propeller have a list of propellers? Since this starting point makes no sense, the other comments, taking this idea literally, are not helpful at all. You should first consider what you want to achieve. What is the *meaning* of `P` and `R` in the superclass?

Comment: @Holger sorry for the misunderstanding. P stands for Product and R for result. In the Propeller class i want to create 1 Propeller made out of 2 blades. In the superclass its just a placeholder to implement other Machines for example. 

Maybe another example: a next subclass would be Turbine with the parameter <Chamber, Turbine> so that a turbine will be made out of 4 chambers. 

To make it more clear: This implementation is not usual. It was just an task in the last programming exam.

Comment: `public class Propeller<Blade, Prop> extends Machine<Blade, Prop>`


With this implementation it's working. This makes no sense to me..

Comment: @MichiSch The type parameters are not “just a placeholder”, as there would be no sense in declaring them if they were not used. As said, the superclass clearly maintains a `List<R>` where `R` is the second type parameter. If that’s the list of components, the machine is made of, the reasonable subclasses would be `Turbine extends Machine<…, Chamber>` and `Propeller extends Machine<…, Blade>`, declaring the components as their second type parameter. The purpose of the first type parameter and `findRessources()` is unclear. Of course, you must create a class named `Blade` before you can use it.

Comment: @Holger ok got you. Maybe the class Name `findRessources()` is unclear. With it i want to check, if there is enough material available. A better name would be `enoughRessourcesAvailable()` which checks if there are 4 chambers available to construct an turbine. If i only add 3 chambers to the List R, the class `enoughRessourcesAvailable()` would return false, because there are 4 pieces needed.

Comment: @MichiSch how can this method return `false` when its return type is `P`? Why do you even have two type parameters, then? Your original question created the impression that the abstract base class was given by the exam and your task was to create the subclasses.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to define the generic types P and R in your abstract class Machine and then use those types in your subclasses. Also, you need to specify the types when you extend the Machine class in your subclasses.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Machine<P, R> {

    public List<R> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public abstract P findResources();
}

public class Conveyor extends Machine<Void, String> {

    @Override
    public Void findResources() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Propeller extends Machine<Blade, Propeller> {

    @Override
    public Blade findResources() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Blade {
    // Define Blade class here
}
```